# Obtaining typescript type of trpc or react-query's useQuery result "data" property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, trpc.io

In my React + TRPC application, I call `const { data: promotion } = trpc.promotions.getPromotion.useQuery({ id: promotionId })` in the client-side. `promotion`'s type is detected by looking at the return type of the actual server-side code:

```
  getPromotion: protectedProcedure
    .input(z.object({ id: z.string() }))
    .query(async({ ctx, input }) => {
      const promotion = await ctx.prisma.promotion.findUniqueOrThrow({
        where: {
          id: input.id
        }
      })

      return {
        ...promotion,
        canModify: false
      }
    })
```

However, I want to use this same type in an interface another component:

```
interface Example {
   promotion: TheDetectedTypeOfGetPromotionReturn??
}
```

The problem is, I can't find a way to "extract" the type I need.

I thought maybe I could use `ReturnType<typeof trpc.promotions.getPromotion.useQuery>['data']` but that just returns `unknown`. Yet, data is a valid type on the returned object.

Here's where the useQuery code is defined: https://github.com/trpc/trpc/blob/9e84d4d9c43de3272aa84bf4110e31e47dc5dda6/packages/react-query/src/shared/hooks/createHooksInternal.tsx#L427

Here's the query base type it uses from react-query: https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/1614c31f84744c62b5bee8f2ff97fc15a1652e86/packages/query-core/src/types.ts#L367

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it like this

```
import {type UseTRPCQueryResult} from '@trpc/react query/shared'
import {type inferRouterOutputs} from '@trpc/server'
import {type TRPCClientErrorLike} from '@trpc/react-query'

type YourType = UseTRPCQueryResult<inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>['promotions']['getPromotions'], TRPCClientErrorLike<AppRouter>>['data']
```

Comment: nice work! Just wrap that in a `NonNullable<>` so it can't be `undefined` and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [documentation](https://trpc.io/docs/client/vanilla/infer-types), you can use something like:

```
import type { inferRouterOutputs } from '@trpc/server';
import type { AppRouter } from './server';
 
type RouterOutput = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>;

type OutputExample = RouterOutput['someRoute']['someQuery'];
```